# Trimming data in Stata

Tags: stata, trim

I have a data set and want to drop 1% of data at one end. For example, I have 3000 observations and I want to drop the 30 highest ones. Is there a command for this kind of trimming? Btw, I am new to Stata.

Comment: Just to point out what should be obvious: Many statistical people consider this kind of dropping of data to be a bad idea. A related but different point is that this is not trimming in the sense of e.g. trimmed means, in which extreme values are ignored, but not deleted. `trimmean` (SSC) is a user-written Stata implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_pctile` in Stata for that.

```
sysuse auto, clear
_pctile weight, nq(100)
return list  #this is optional 
drop if weight>r(r99) #top 1 percent
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the cutoff is for your drop you can use:

```
drop if var1>300
```

which drops all rows with `var1` over 300.

You can use `summarize var1, detail` to get the key percentiles: it will give you 1% and 99% percentiles along with other standard percentiles.

Answer (score 0):

To select 30 top observations in stata, use the following command:

```
keep  if (_n<=30 )
```

To drop top 30 observations in stata, use the following command

```
keep if (_n>30)
```

Comment: This is misleading as an answer without an explanation that you must `sort` first and separately deal with missing values.